# convert a list of class data frame objects into objects of class matrix - list

Tags: r, class, lapply

I have a list of data frames. Each data frame has 6 rows and 6 columns. They are all numbers, however, all data frames have their elements as class character.
Example:

```
$`A`
         V1       V2    V3     V4      V5       V6
V1    0.1212     0.6231 0.4431 0.3213  0.6578 0.1259
V2               2.1234 0.6532 0.9845  0.8743 0.8732
V3                      0.2314 0.7648  0.7634 0.8732
V4                             0.1234  0.6544 0.3456
V5                                     0.7653 0.9812
V6                                            0.1265

$`B`
        V1       V2    V3     V4      V5       V6
V1    0.2345     0.1234 0.5647 0.7891  0.6721 0.3259
V2               1.1334 0.4332 0.1245  0.2343 0.5332
V3                      0.2914 0.1648  0.2334 0.1232
V4                             0.1234  0.6744 0.5656
V5                                     0.3553 0.9812
V6                                            0.4665
```

I would like to change all data frames of the list to class matrix (numerical).
I tried:

```
lapply (list, data.matrix)
```

but the result is a list of data frames with integers. Example:

```
     V1   V2    V3   V4   V5   V6
V1    2    2    2    2    2    4    
V2    1    3    4    5    5    7    
V3    1    1    3    4    6    3    
V4    1    1    1    3    4    5    
V5    1    1    1    1    1    1    
V6    1    1    1    1    1    1
```

Also tried to run

```
lapply(list, as.matrix)
```

however, I got a list of quoted matrices, like this:

```
$`A`
         V1       V2       V3       V4        V5       V6
V1    "0.1212"   "0.6231" "0.4431" "0.3213"  "0.6578" "0.1259"
V2               "2.1234" "0.6532" "0.9845"  "0.8743" "0.8732"
V3                        "0.2314" "0.7648"  "0.7634" "0.8732"
V4                                 "0.1234"  "0.6544" "0.3456"
V5                                           "0.7653" "0.9812"
V6                                                    "0.1265"
```

How can I convert these data frames of my list from character class to matrix class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may loop over the `list`, then loop over the data.frame columns with `lapply` convert to numeric and assign it back to the original data.frame object and return the data.frame ('x')

```
list <- lapply(list, function(x) {x[] <- lapply(x, as.numeric);x})
```

If those are factor columns, convert to `character` first and then to `numeric`

```
lapply(list, function(x) {x[] <- lapply(x, function(y) as.numeric(as.character(y)))
           x})
```

Comment: I read these data frames from a csv file using read.csv. Is there an argument that I can use that would not make the elements of the data frame of character class?

Comment: @BMT Yes, I assume that the blank elements are read as `""`.  You may use `na.strings = ""` in `read.csv`

Comment: didn't work use `na.strings =  ""`. The elements of the data.frame are still as character and when I try to run `lapply(list, as.matrix)` all elements will be double-quoted as my example. That's my final goal, to make them as matrix.

Comment: @BMT Then, probably some other element is in your data that is a character and should be included in the `na.strings`.  `as.matrix` returns character if any element is character as matrix can hold only a single class

Comment: @BMT if you want a matrix at the end, then why not do `lapply(list, function(x) {x[] <- lapply(x, as.numeric);as.matrix(x)})`

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to numeric and then reset the matrix order:

```r
lapply(dfs, function(x) matrix(as.numeric(x), ncol = n_cols))
```

Data

```r
set.seed(1L)
n_cols <- 6
n_total <- 36
a <- matrix(rnorm(n_total), ncol = n_cols)
b <- matrix(rnorm(n_total), ncol = n_cols)
a[lower.tri(a)] <- ""
b[lower.tri(b)] <- ""
dfs <- list(a, b)
```

Comment: it does not work in my data. error: " 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double' ". I got the same error when I try use ```lapply (list, as.numeric).

Comment: That's interesting - on my machine this code runs without error and produces the output you're expecting.  It's all base R code, so it couldn't be a package version issue.  Hard to imagine it is an R version issue (I'm using R 4.0.5).  Are you saying that if you use the example data I created and run the `lapply` solution, you get that error?  Or are you running it on other data?

Comment: It didn't work when I use my data. It worked running your example. However, my data frame elements are characters (differently from your example). They are numbers, but it was read as characters in my data frame.